# RF signals database

Tags: signal-analysis, sampling

I'm trying to learn more about RF signal modulation/demodulation. I wanted to experiment with some real signals, but I don't have any data to work on.

Is there any open database of RF signals? Like a set of signals with known characteristics modulated with AM, analog FM, digital QAM, ... Raw data (directly from ADC) would be perfect, so I can do all decoding stages myself.

I tried to look for it on google, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: See also [this paper](https://peer.asee.org/rf-signal-database-for-a-communication-systems-course).

Answer (score 4):

You might check out the [signal identification wiki](https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Signal_Identification_Guide) site.

They have samples of many different modulation schemes.  Many have information about the signals (how they are generated and decoded, who uses them, what information they usually contain.)

All of the signals were captured "in the wild" - they are all samples of real signals in use somewhere in the world.

Some of the signals aren't identified - Sigid is all about identifying signals that people have discovered on the air.

Some of the examples are audio only, others have recorded IQ raw data.